# Redux Best Practices for Rerouting

Tags: api, express, redux, react-redux

Currently modeling some auth in the Redux-React convention with an Express API have a login component.

My Login Component creates an Action with ajax data passed in as a function. in this action, the ajax mutation is performed, resulting in an object that returns

```
  { 
    'errors': '' or whatever was handled in exception,
    'user': 'user token for logging in client', 
    'redirect': 'url for redirection 
  }
```

I am then taking the action and dispatching a call to a "LOGGED_IN" action with the json object as payload, where it calls the auth reducer and updates the user token in the auth state.

At this point, I am at the login page. Is the redux best practice way for handling login redirects-

A) Create a check on componentwillmount in login that checks for existence of auth and redirects to dashboard

B) Reroute via Redux-Router Link in the Action after the dispatch call (pretty sure its not this one...)

C) something else

In non-redux environments I would deal with the callback in component, store the user token in a cache, and then just rerender the route

Comment: Hi, I suggest storing the token of the user in localStorage instead of using redux
and the creates an HOC (high order component) to check if the user has a token can see the component if not will be redirected to login page.

Comment: @StevenDanielAnderson thanks for helping out and answering that day. I've since learned that indeed we should store tokens in app memory, and http-only cookies are the safer alternative to localStorage to prevent XSS attacks